# slide up div if the height is smaller than the div before

Tags: jquery

I made a tab content box and I'm trying to make it that if the active tab's content is longer than the next content clicked the div will slide up instead of just moving into the auto-height. is there a way to do this using jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean?

http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/

There are demos on the page.

**EDIT**:

I assume with your question about which tab should slide up, without knowing the exact behavior you're trying to achieve I can't say for sure. I can assume it's something like the following.

1. Page loads, two tabs, tab one is
   selected and already visible.
2. User clicks tab two
3. Slide up all tab content since this
   will have no affect on any tabs not
   visible.
4. Slide down tab number two content

Comment: Not exactly. I tried using that but I don't know how to do it depending on which tab you click.

Comment: Something like that but with 4 tabs. I'll try to slide up and down the whole div and not just the content to see if that helps.